# MuleEventContext with annotation

Tags: mule

I want to avoid using the `Callable` interface in a Mule component, instead of this i want to use annotations based coding.

I am using the following code but getting an error.

How can i use the annotation based approach?

```
public Object processEvent(@Lookup MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception  {
  System.out.println("eventContext: " + eventContext.getMessage().getPayload());
  return "GOT IT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Lookup+Annotation):

> The Lookup annotation is used to inject objects from the Mule registry

The `MuleEventContext` is not a registry object but a dynamic one, so this can not work.

What do you need the `MuleEventContext` for?

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. i want my application with annotation  based approach. Could you tell me Credentials vault for mule security which version of mule studio available. Because i am seeing Documentation for Credentials Vault but i can't find in mule Studio.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between Credentials Vault, Mule Studio and annotation-based coding. Can you please specify what you do need the `MuleEventContext` for? Maybe there's another way to get you what you need.